# Writing a Code in vb to stream screenshots from mobile through ADB

Tags: vb.net, stream, adb, screenshot

am trying to write a code in VB to stream screenshots from my android device to my PC, I tried to use the following adb commands inside a timer

```
adb shell screencap /sdcard/screen.png 
adb pull /sdcard/screen.png C:\screen.png
```

what will happen is that the pull command will pull the screenshot before it finish
I tried some sleep command, but it will make the display very slow, and eventually because I send too many adb commands the device will become slow and it will hang in the end

is there any idea to take a fast screenshot or a stream of video and transfer it to my pc through adb command

Answer (score 0):

Your problem most likely was not with screencap/pull sequence in the same iteration but with the next screencap overwriting the image before the previous pull was completed. Are you using a semaphore to make sure that the next frame capture would not fire before the previous one finishes?

Also do not use `/sdcard` folder to store the captured image. Find a `tmpfs` partition on your device and use that instead.

Comment: What is semaphore, ill try to use the tmpfs but I searched of how to do that, there is no clear way for android, do you know how to do that ?